# Converting NSData that contains UTF-8 and null bytes to string

Tags: objective-c, string, nsdata, c-strings

I have an __NSCFData object. I know what's inside it.

`61 70 70 6c 65 2c 74 79 70 68 6f 6f 6e 00 41 52 4d 2c 76 38 00`

I tried converting it to a string with initWithData: and stringWithUTF8String: and it gives me "apple,typhoon". The conversion is terminated at 00

The data actually is

```
61 a
70 p
70 p
6c l
65 e
2c ,
74 t
79 y
70 p
68 h
6f o
6f o
6e n
00 (null)
41 A
52 R
4d M
2c ,
76 v
38 8
00 (null)
```

How can I properly convert this without loss of information?

Comment: Here is a potential solution: https://pastebin.com/B8k1ywWZ I used the `rangeOfData:options:range:` that works like the `NSString` version ones (`rangeOfString:options:range:`) and applied a similar logic to the one looking for iterating and not stopping only at first occurence. It's "high" level method not playing that much with bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [`stringWithUTF8String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497379-stringwithutf8string?preferredLanguage=occ) describes its first parameter as:

> A NULL-terminated C array of bytes in UTF8 encoding.

Which is why your conversion stops at the first null byte.

What you appear to have is a collection of C strings packed into a single `NSData`. You can convert each one individually. Use the `NSData` methods `bytes` and `length` to obtain a pointer to the bytes/first C string and the total number of bytes respectively. The standard C function `strlen()` will give you the length in bytes of an individual string. Combine these and some simple pointer arithmetic and you can write a loop which converts each string and, for example, stores them all into an array or concatenates them.

If you get stuck implementing the solution ask a new question, show your code, and explain the issue. Someone will undoubtedly help you with the next step.

HTH

Comment: Indeed, the data is two strings. I consider your solution as a little more 'proper' since you took into consideration the possibility that the data can be two strings. Both strings are terminated at null. I wrote a program combining your solution and greymouser's solution.
https://ideone.com/CxzBlv
Please check it and let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: In your solution you use `getBytes` rather than `bytes`, which gives you a redundant copy of the data. You can just use the pointer returned by `bytes` directly and some pointer arithmetic to advance it to the next string. Also rather than sticking with whole string conversion using `stringWithUTF8String` you’ve gone with character-at-a-time and `appendFormat:`, adding more inefficiency — stick with your original whole string approach.

Comment: Much better. A quick scan suggests your logic for handling empty strings isn't quite right, you lose the following string, and if the last (or only) string isn't null terminated you lose that - but you correctly never read past the end of your data. You have to decide whether you need to handle empty strings and/or missing nulls, depends on what level on input validation you require.

Answer (score 0):

0, or null, is the sentinel value which terminates strings, so you're going to have to deal with it somehow if you want to automatically dump the bytes into a string. If you don't, the string, or things that try to print it, for example, will assume the end of string is reached when reaching the NULL.

Just replace the bytes as they occur with something printable, like a space. Use whatever value works for you.

Example:

```
// original data you have from somewhere
char something[] = "apple,typhoon\0ARM,v8\0";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:something length:sizeof(something)];

// Find each null terminated string in the data
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString string];
const char *bytes = [data bytes];
for (int i = 0; i < [data length]; i++) {
    unsigned char byte = (unsigned char)bytes[i];
    if (byte == 0) {
        if ([temp length] > 0) {
            [strings addObject:temp];
            temp = [NSMutableString string];
        }
    } else {
        [temp appendFormat:@"%c", byte];
    }
}

// Results
NSLog(@"strings count: %lu", [strings count]);
[strings enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *string, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"%ld: %@", idx, string);
}];
// strings count: 2
// 0: apple,typhoon
// 1: ARM,v8
```

Comment: `\0` or `0` (not `null`, what is a pointer) terminates *C* strings. Instances of `NSString` are not C strings.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Yes, null is a pointer to 0. But that's not what is being discussed here. A null terminated string is a string that ends in 0, which is exactly what I wrote above "0, or null, is the sentinel value which terminates string". Instances of NSString are obviously not C strings -- and that's why I wrote my answer the way I did -- there is no way to box a char[] with a null in the middle of it into an NSString and have it not terminate the string. Try `NSLog(@"hello\0there");` or any variation thereof and let me know how it goes.

Comment: The C string is 0-terminated, not null-terminated. Indeed, this is not important. I put it in parenthesis. However, I did add a 0 in an instance of NSString in my answer. This is quite simple, because even NSString literals are not 0-terminated. Just look to my answer. NSString is length-based. Replacing 0 with spaces or whatsoever is terrible, because doing so, information is lost.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad C strings are null terminated. I don't know what else to do but quote K&R's C guide -- "... the character '\0', the *null character*, whose value is zero)" (p.28 - "The C Progamming Language", Kernighan and Ritche. Prentice Hall. 1988). I get that you want people to understand that that null pointers and null termination are semantically different concepts, but everyone refers to C-strings as null-terminated character arrays. It's just what they are.

Comment: I wrote something similar with the suggestion from CRD. Your solution works too. I'm still a little bit confused by the discussion about C strings here. The value of \0 is 0 and it's the null character. And the string is terminated when null is reached. Can't it be called 'null-terminated' then?

Comment: @LordStiltskin Yes, it can and *should* be called null terminated. K&R even call them null terminated. We went on a tangent, but I couldn’t let it go! :-)

Comment: @LordStiltskin - It is indeed a [null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). The confusion arises as "null" is used both in the *null character* – meaning the ASCII NUL or zero bytes, and in the *null pointer* – being the C term for the value returned by casting `0` to `void *`, and both are often just shortened to *null*. Objective-C adds to the fun by using the term *nil pointer* if the type of the pointer is an Objective-C object type, but sticking with *null pointer* otherwise.

Comment: @CRD Yes, this is the ASCII `NUL`. In the Q of his answer, it looks like `NULL`. However, this is not important, whether I put the remark in parenthesis. The important point is, that instances of `NSString` are not 0-terminated.

Comment: @greymouser Wow, K&R. Did you do some historic research? Have a look to the C standard … However, this is not important It is important, that instances of `NSString` does not work with 0-termination either way you call it. This makes your answer meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the intention of some answers, the stored strings in instances of `NSString` are *not* 0-terminated. Even there might be problems with writing them out (since underlying C functions for output expects a 0-terminated string), the instances itself can contain a `\0`:

```
NSString *zeroIncluded = @"A\0B";
NSLog(@"%ld", [zeroIncluded length]);
// prints 3
```

To create such an instance you can use methods that have a `bytes` and a `length` parameter, i. e. `-initWithBytes:length:encoding:`. Therefore something like this should work:

```
NSData *data = …
[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, as intended by CRD, you might check, whether you want to have such a string.

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't answer OP's question. He was asking how to get "all" the data in his NSData that is effectively "apple,typhoon\0ARM,v8\0". It was terminating at "apple,typhoon" and he wanted to get at the rest of it.

Comment: I could have used this technique but as CRD suggested, it's two strings packed into data. So, it's better to just extract both as separate string. 
Thanks you for the information. I didn't really know NSStrings aren't 0 terminated. However, even if I use the NSString in UIAlertView or UILabel, the complete string isn't used.

Comment: @greymouser With the above code, he gets *all* the data. Just try it.

Comment: @LordStiltskin Yes, it depends on your problem, esp. what you want to do with the strings, whether it is useful to do it that way. However, your Q was, how to get the whole text in one string. This is the answer to that Q.